VBA code to prevent overlapping data labels on doughnut chart
I have a doughnut chart created through VBA.
When it creates it, the data labels are overlapping on the chart.
I want the labels to be slightly to the side of the chart sections with leader lines.
Here is what I tried but it failed:
chartSeries.DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
Thanks in advance!

Please provide the screenshot and the peace of the code. There are no doughnut chart experts here, but Excel VBA experts who are able to solve this task, but more details are required.

I can think of at least one person who occasionally posts on here that could be thought of as a doughnut chart expert.   That aside - the post by Chris Neilsen might help, it's not written for a doughnut chart though:  Excel macro to fix overlapping data labels in line chart
